# 'open link in new tab' option missing when right clicking a link on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

when i use `<a href="link">` it works and option for new tab can be seen in context menu on right clicking the link . but if i use JavaScript/jQuery its not showing? i used window.location,window.open etc but it doesn't show. now i am using onclick attribut on div,but still not showing. does it only shows when using anchor?

```
div class='miniShell'>          <!-- m1 m2 m3 m4 used for seperate goto links   search if 'mp3' you will find next usage -->
      <div class='mini' onclick="openLink('<?php echo $UrlA?>')"> <img src=''>  <div class="miniTitle"><?php echo ucwords($TitleA) ?></div>   </div>
      <div class='mini' onclick="openLink('<?php echo $UrlB?>')"> <img src=''><div class="miniTitle"><?php echo ucwords($TitleB) ?></div>   </div>
      <div class='mini' onclick="openLink('<?php echo $UrlC?>')"> <img src=''>  <div class="miniTitle"><?php echo ucwords($TitleC) ?></div>   </div>
      <div class='mini' onclick="openLink('<?php echo $UrlD?>')"> <img src=''><div class="miniTitle"><?php echo ucwords($TitleD) ?></div>   </div>
     </div>
```

in jquery:

```
function openLink(link){
                 window.open('http://localhost/mysite/story/'+link,'_self');
             }
```

Browser:google chrome

Comment: change `_self` to `_blank`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div isn't a link. To create a link use the  tag. You could replace the div tag with an a tag that has virtually the same methods to achieve this goal. Although your HTML redirects the page to a certain link, the browser doesn't classify it as a "link".

Comment: hi,thanks for answer .so if i give it href attribute using jquery is it gonna work or no.

Comment: Yeah, if the tag type is Anchor (<a>).

Comment: needs href="#" to work

Answer (score 0):

Continue to @Rigidity answer, too a window.open is a function, is not a generic link, it is a javascript method, and the browser will not recognize it as a link and hence the contextmenu of a normal link will not apper in your div

Comment: hi,thanks for answer .so if i give it href attribute using jquery is it gonna work or no

Comment: That could work, but you too can do a tooltip to show the link , but is better remove all these openLink, and use **a href** Tag, and is suggest you remove all php word, use <? ?> instead <?php ?>